# Operator with two last elements from Observable in RxSwift

Tags: observable, reactive-programming, rx-swift, reactive

I have an observable sequence of `Int`s:

```
-1-2-3-4-5-6-3-4-5-1-
```

For example, I need to detect when the previous element was bigger than the last one.

In this sequence it's `(6, 3)` and `(5, 1)`:

```
-1-2-3-4-5-6-3-4-5-1-
-------------ˆ-----ˆ-
```

Which operator I can use in this case?

Comment: Can `scan` operator help?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes `scan` is operator you looking for:

```
let stream = Observable<Int>.from([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 3, 4, 5, 1])
let seed = (0, 0) // (any Int, Int that smaller of all possible values of first emited Int)
let wrongPairs = stream
    .scan(seed) { last, new -> (Int, Int) in
        return (last.1, new)
    }
    .filter { $0.0 > $0.1 }
```

With `scan` we map stream of `Int`s to stream of `Int` pairs and then filter all pairs that are "good" (previous element if smaller or equal):

```
-1-2-3-4-5-6-3-4-5-1-
-(0, 1)-(1, 2)-(2, 3)-(3, 4)-(4, 5)-(5, 6)-(6, 3)-(3, 4)-(4, 5)-(5, 1)-
-(6, 3)-(5, 1)-
```

Disadvantage of `scan` that you need initial number to start with, which can be problematic in some cases, but if your stream always emit positive numbers `-1` will work.